# Fedora 20: frequent 20-30 second lockups, dodgy USB port at fault?

Tags: linux, usb, fedora

Brand new Fedora 20 install, all working fine other than occasional, seemingly random lockups. The 5s load average comes back in the 10-15 range immediately afterwards, so *something* is getting done at the expense of everything else in these periods. I've not managed to get anything useful out of top, other than a high wa % (60+) again, immediately after the lockups. Memory usage seems unrelated - it's consistently low.

Logs show only one real anomaly, but plenty of it. The following line is spammed many (50+) times a second:

```
ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: port 3 resume error -110
```

I tried unplugging all USB devices, and even at boot a similar error (same port, but now complaining about a "reset error") appeared. The USB devices I generally have connected work fine in other boxes.

I'm quite happy to disable the USB port if it'll convince the damn thing to behave, but I don't know if that's the best solution or even the correct one. Could anyone please advise?